# ImageView with rounded corners after scaling with ScaleType.CenterCrop

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview, crop, rounded-corners

I am trying to crop an image and then round the corners so that it appears more nicely on the screen.

What I've been able to do is round the corners of the image, but the cropping will sometimes cut off the  sides of the image (depending on the size/aspect ratio of the image).

So what I would like to do is perform the crop, THEN apply the rounded corners. How can I do this?

Rounding the corners of the image:

```
private Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
    Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

    final int color = 0xff000000;
    final Paint paint = new Paint();
    final Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
    final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
    final float roundpx = 20;

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundpx, roundpx, paint);

    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
    canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

    return output;
}
```

And then I set the imageview's scaletype like so: `imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_CROP)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you wrap your imageview with cardview, you achieve.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/your_image" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: This is a pretty decent solution! Just note that if you only want rounded corners and no shadow, set `cardElevation` to 0 or leave it out. Also, in most cases nowadays, you'd probably leave out `cardUseCompatPadding` (default is false).

Comment: Very simple and effective solution! I was going crazy with complex solutions that didn't keep aspect ratio. Also, I'm using a `cardCornerRadius` that is half of layout size for a circle effect.

Comment: What about stroke that will be around the image? For some reason, when I try adding it, I always get some leftover pixels (black, or white, or of the image itself). Even using the new `MaterialCardView` class that has the ability to set stroke has this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112064791

Comment: Making it the child of cardview increases load time and during recyclerview it lags.

Answer (score 1):

try this one :

```
public class RoundedImageView extends ImageView {

private Path mMaskPath;
private Paint mMaskPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
private int mCornerRadius = 10;

public RoundedImageView(Context context) {
    super(context);

    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet) {
    super(context, attributeSet);

    init();
}

public RoundedImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    init();
}

private void init() {
    ViewCompat.setLayerType(this, ViewCompat.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    mMaskPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
}


public void setCornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
    mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;
    generateMaskPath(getWidth(), getHeight());
    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldW, int oldH) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldW, oldH);

    if (w != oldW || h != oldH) {
        generateMaskPath(w, h);
    }
}

private void generateMaskPath(int w, int h) {
    mMaskPath = new Path();
    mMaskPath.addRoundRect(new RectF(0,0,w,h), mCornerRadius, mCornerRadius, Path.Direction.CW);
    mMaskPath.setFillType(Path.FillType.INVERSE_WINDING);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(canvas.isOpaque()) { // If canvas is opaque, make it transparent
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 255, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
    }

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    if(mMaskPath != null) {
        canvas.drawPath(mMaskPath, mMaskPaint);
    }
}
```

and

```
<your.pack.name.RoundedImageView
            android:id="@+id/image_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

RoundedImageView  iconImage = (RoundedImageView )findViewById(R.id.image_id);
iconImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory) for this, if you indeed use ImageView . Example:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun getCircularDrawable(context: Context, bitmap: Bitmap): RoundedBitmapDrawable {
            val size = Math.min(bitmap.width, bitmap.height)
            val centerCropBitmap = ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(bitmap, size, size)
            val roundedBitmapDrawable = RoundedBitmapDrawableFactory.create(context.resources, centerCropBitmap)
            roundedBitmapDrawable.isFilterBitmap = true
            roundedBitmapDrawable.setAntiAlias(true)
            roundedBitmapDrawable.isCircular = true
            return roundedBitmapDrawable
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        imageView.setImageDrawable(getCircularDrawable(this, BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.test)))
    }
}
```

And the result :

[image]

The disadvantage is that I can't find a way to provide it with just the original bitmap, so I had to do a center-crop on it first. I've requested to have this ability [**here**](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/112231681).